# Discord.py app_command.Argument causing TypeError

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I'm currently stuck on what is probably a dumb error, since I started to work on a Discord bot two days ago, but after googling this in every possible ways, I didn't found anything that could be solving my problem.

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

Intents = discord.Intents.default()
Intents.guild_messages = True
Intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=Intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="mycommandname", guild = discord.Object(id = MyDiscordGuild))
@app_commands.Argument(name="NewParameter0", required = True)
@app_commands.Argument(name="NewParameter1", required = True)
@app_commands.Argument(name="NewParameter2", required = False)
async def mycommandname(interaction: discord.Interaction, NewParameter0: str, NewParameter1: str, NewParameter2: str):
            
    Parameter0 = NewParameter0
    Parameter1 = NewParameter1
    Parameter2 = NewParameter2

    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Validation message", delete_after=60)
```

And this is the error that comes to me:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
  File "PathToMyDiscordPYScript", line X, in <module>
    @app_commands.Argument(name="NewParameter0")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

As you probably guessed, I'm trying to do a slash command with 3 different input arguments. I already figured out that I needed to add those @app_commands.Argument(name="") for each arguments I needed as inputs, but I definitely can't figure out why do I have this TypeError from nowhere.

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide me,
Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `@app_commands.Argument()` to create a command parameter, it is enough with adding it in the function header:

```
@tree.command(name="mycommandname", guild = discord.Object(id = MyDiscordGuild))
async def mycommandname(interaction: discord.Interaction, new_parameter_1: str, new_parameter_2: str, new_parameter_3: str = ""):

    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Validation message", delete_after=60)
```

Notes:

1. Parameter names can't contain upper case or spaces.
2. In order to make a parameter optional, define a default value in the function header (`new_parameter_3: str = ""`).
3. Reminder that you need to [`sync()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=tree%20sync#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.sync) the tree for the changes to be applied.
4. You can additionally use [`@app_commands.describe()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands%20describe#discord.app_commands.describe) to describe the parameter:

```
@tree.command(name="mycommandname", guild = discord.Object(id = MyDiscordGuild))
@app_commands.describe(new_parameter_1="Description for parameter 1")
@app_commands.describe(new_parameter_2="Description for parameter 2")
@app_commands.describe(new_parameter_3="Description for parameter 3")
async def mycommandname(interaction: discord.Interaction, new_parameter_1: str, new_parameter_2: str, new_parameter_3: str = ""):
    await interaction.response.send_message("a")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my first code was actually containing upper case characters, which was the reason for the error I had when my commands were trying to sync with the server (HTTP status 400, error code 50035).

You definitely saved me from a big headache